# Mockito throw Exception

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, testng, mockito

```
@Test(expectedExceptions=DataAccessException.class)
public void testUpdateSubModuleOrderDateExceptionCheck() {
    //some code to initialize//
    UserSubModuleDao userSubModuleDao = mock(UserSubModuleDao.class);
    userModuleServiceImpl.setUserSubModuleDao(userSubModuleDao);
    UserSubModule userSubModule=new UserSubModule();
    UserSubModuleId userSubModuleId=new UserSubModuleId();
      when(userSubModuleDao.findById(any(UserSubModuleId.class),eq(false))).thenThrow(DataAccessException.class);

    userModuleServiceImpl.updateSubModuleOrder(data, moduleSysId, userId);
```

I want to throw the Db exception for code coverage . its working if i give expected exception as : `Exception.class` but not for `DataAccessException.class`

My method in original class is as following:

```
public void updateSubModuleOrder(Long[] data, Long moduleSysId, Long userId) {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            SubModule subModule=new SubModule();
            subModule.setSubModuleId(data[i]);
            UserSubModuleId userSubModuleId = new UserSubModuleId();
            userSubModuleId.setSubModuleId(subModule);
            userSubModuleId.setUserId(userId);
            userSubModuleId.setUserModuleId(moduleSysId);
            UserSubModule userSubmodule = new UserSubModule();
            userSubmodule = userSubModuleDao.findById(userSubModuleId,
                    false);
catch (DataAccessException ewmsDataExp) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "Database Exception while updateSubModuleOrder because of {}",
                ewmsDataExp.getMessage());
        throw new EWMSServiceException(
                "Database Exception while updateSubModuleOrder"
                        + ewmsDataExp.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        LOGGER.error(
                "System Exception while updateSubModuleOrder because of {}",
                exp.getMessage());
        throw new EWMSServiceException(
                "Database Exception while updateSubModuleOrder"
                        + exp.getMessage());
    }*
```

i get the error

```
FAILED: testUpdateSubModuleOrderDateExceptionCheck
org.testng.TestException: 
**Expected exception org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException but got    org.testng.TestException:** 
**Expected exception org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException but got         java.lang.InstantiationError: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException**
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleInvocationResults(Invoker.java:1497)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1245)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

## **and some error lines.**...

```
Default test
```

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================

===============================================

Comment: Why are you expecting a `DataAccessException` when your class explicitly catches `DataAccessException` and converts it to something else?

Answer (score 64):

Change this:

```
thenThrow(DataAccessException.class)
```

to

```
thenThrow(new DataAccessException("..."){ })
```

Example:

```
when(userSubModuleDao.findById(any(UserSubModuleId.class),eq(false))).thenThrow(new DataAccessException("..."){});
```

You can only pass a Class reference when that Exception type has a No-Arg constructor, and the Spring exception does not have one.

Comment: it says DataAccessException cannot be instantiatied

Comment: Yes, it says the class cannot be instantiated because it tries to use a no-arg constructor to make it. And the class has no such constructor.

Comment: `DataAccessException` is an abstract class, so you can't instantiate it. You can use `new DataRetrievalFailureException("reason")` instead

Comment: it is still giving errors..."java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException"...even I have used 'new DataAccessException("..."){}'

Comment: Worked for me, +1, but what is that { } doing?

Answer (score 32):

Try

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject).methodName(...);
```

Comment: This is a more correct answer because when...thenThrow doesn't work with the methods that return void.

Comment: @SaurabhPatil - How will you solve the issue where void method throws exception?

Comment: @PAA Do you mean to say you want void method to throw an exception during testing? Yes that's exactly the reason why this answer is better than the other one.

Answer (score 8):

As stated by Jen S:

> You can only pass a Class reference when that Exception type has a No-Arg constructor, and the Spring exception does not have one.

My solution was using Mockito:

```
Mockito.when(mockedObject.method(Mockito.anyString())).thenThrow(Mockito.mock(DataAccessException.class));
```

Comment: very helpful and quick solution.. Thanks